# update UI of Xamarin Form in Portbale after running fragment in Xamarin Droid

Tags: c#, android-fragments, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am getting scanned barcode in Xamarin Droid in fragment and passing that data in Portable Xamarin Form. Now in Portable code, I am receiving this data using property and event  in TabbedPage and then passing it to its selected Child Page (Content Page) . Now I want to update UI with addition of related data using passed scanned data.

However when I debug code, after coming with data from fragment(from Droid app) and passing to Content Child Page, I can not call OnAppearing() method where I am updating listview control. I tried with calling it is separate method also.

I am getting error which sound like can not update UI of one thread from another thread.( Sorry can not give exact error message as currently device is not with me)

And this error occurred only after taking data from fragment, If I tried with adding data directing from page, its working perfect.

Comment: Could you please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show what you are trying?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late reply but I got the solution for it.As I was passing data from fragment(another thread type activity) to my page( which is actually on Main thread) it was not allowing me.

Solution I found for it as simply call refresh code on my page inside

```
 Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
   {
      // Perform Refresh listview operation etc.
   }
```